# How do I assign the Output of a command as a Value of a variable?

Tags: bash, scripts, sh

I have a simple bash script like below :

```
#!/bin/bash

hname='hostname'
echo Hello, my server name is $hname
```

But the output is not as I expected. It is as below :

> Hello, my server name is hostname

But my hostname is not 'hostname', it is actually 'User'.  How should I make it seen as that?

> Hello, my server name is User

Comment: https://www.systutorials.com/241700/how-to-get-the-hostname-of-the-node-in-bash/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to get the output of a certain command as a string that should be assigned as value of a variable you need to use the [command substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Substitution.html) builtin functionality:

```
#!/bin/bash
hname="$(hostname)"
echo "Hello, my server name is $hname"
```

Also you can use the old style of command substitution that is supported by bash (and dash/sh) and is the only one within some other shells:

```
#!/bin/bash
hname=`hostname`
echo "Hello, my server name is $hname"
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want the variable `hname` to contain your hostname, use this syntax:

`hname=$(hostname)`

Answer (score 0):

You want to use `$HOSTNAME` to get the variable. `"hostname"` will be treated as a constant.